# How to pause execution yet keep webbrowser control loading in C#

Tags: c#, .net, browser, timer, sleep

I'm trying to make a web browser that tells me when a specific video is done. I already know how to get the time in seconds of how long it takes. I just need to know how to wait to execute the next step without stopping the webbrowser control (which needs to play the flash video).

Any ideas? I've been looking into the Timer class, but can't figure out how to apply it to this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try `Thread.Sleep()` (You're not clear about what threads are running what...), except this idea is doomed to failure.  I mean, you are going to let him *pause* the video, aren't you?

(Yes, You are!)